# How to Show image in tree view when there are no records?

Tags: html, image, odoo, odoo-15, odoo-16

I want to show image in tree view when there are no records. Can this be possible inside this code.

```
<record id="action_partner_form" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Customers</field>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
            <field name="res_model">res.partner</field>
            <field name="view_mode">kanban,tree,form</field>
            <field name="context">{'res_partner_search_mode': 'customer'}</field>
            <field name="search_view_id" ref="view_res_partner_filter"/>
            <field name="help" type="html">
              <p class="o_view_nocontent_smiling_face">
                Create a Contact in your address book
              </p><p>
                Odoo helps you track all activities related to your contacts.
              </p>
            </field>
</record>
```

I tried to put `<img src="static/description/icon.png"/>` in help but it is showing as no image.

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the module name in the src as below:

```
<img src="/base/static/description/icon.png" class="img img-fluid o_we_custom_image"/>
```